# No tf data.Fixed Frame my_frame does not exist

Tags: ros, rviz, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm following  the rviz tutorial basic shapes.
I  change the cpp file and set both fixed and target frame to "my_frame" not "/my_frame" because when i typed it automatically change to "my_frame".
But when i star rivz, it still said Fixed Frame my_frame does not exist. is there something i missed? thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134131/no-tf-data.fixed-frame-my_frame-does-not-exist/) by [Neothera](https://answers.ros.org/users/12526/neothera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-02-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I believe there is no tf frame being published with /my_frame name. That tutorial just talks about an arbitrary frame called /my_frame and if you have set of tf already being published then you could map your markers to one of the frame and get it working for your project. To know how to create a tf please check the http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials

Hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2014-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since you are following your tutorial from : http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes

Just remove the slash('/') in *my_frame*, i.e, change this in your *src/basic_shapes.cpp*

```
47     marker.header.frame_id = "/my_frame";
```

changed to

```
47     marker.header.frame_id = "my_frame";
```

This fixed the issue for me. Hope it does for you too.

---

Originally posted by [kushal](https://answers.ros.org/users/109545/kushal/) with karma: 11 on 2022-07-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Schrodingers_Tiger](https://answers.ros.org/users/126128/schrodingers_tiger/) on 2022-12-05**:
It works for me. Thank U!